# how to convert from fopen to open when trying to open a .data file?

Tags: c, linux, system

```
FILE *inFile = fopen("dataFlow.dat", "r"); // read only
FILE *outFile = fopen("report.dat", "w"); // write only
```

Comment: What have you tried? [`fopen`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html) vs. [`open`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) would seem a reasonable place to start.

Comment: fopen you can open whatever. What do you mean by .dat file? What is in the .dat file?

Comment: Why? There are legitimate reasons... but `fopen()` is defined by the Standard, `open()` isn't.

Comment: And `open()` returns an integer file descriptor, not a `FILE *`, so you cannot use the result the same way. (Unless you wrap it in a `FILE *` via `fdopen()`, but then what was the point of avoiding `fopen()`?)

Comment: You probably want a binary file; (it's difficult to guess why some systems seemingly translate certain values.)

Comment: Please note that a certain amount of research is expected before asking a question. See [this guide](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/) for further information.

Comment: @Ethb: even as the question has been closed, you can accept one of the answers by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.

Answer (score 2):

If your files have binary contents, you should open them in binary mode by appending `b` to the mode string.

For better portability and to take advantage of buffering, using standard streams is recommended over system call such as `open`, which are tricky to use reliably.

```
FILE *inFile = fopen("dataFlow.dat", "rb"); // read only
FILE *outFile = fopen("report.dat", "wb"); // write only
```

For low level system programming on POSIX systems, you can use the `open()` system call.

Here is a small example that just attempts to copy 1KB from one file to the other:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    unsigned char buf[1024];
    int status = 0;

    int inFile = open("dataFlow.dat", O_RDONLY);
    if (inFile < 0) {
        perror("dataFlow.dat");
        return 1;
    }

    int outFile = open("report.dat", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0666);
    if (outFile < 0) {
        perror("report.dat");
        close(inFile);
        return 1;
    }

    // this loop is equivalent to nread = fread(buffer, 1, sizeof buffer, inFile);
    int nread = 0;
    while (nread < (int)sizeof(buffer)) {
        ssize_t nr = read(inFile, buffer + nread, sizeof buffer - nread);
        if (nr < 0) {
            if (errno == EINTR)
                continue;
            perror("reading dataFlow");
            status = 1;
            break;
        }
        if (nr == 0)
            break;
        nread += nr;
    }

    // this loop is equivalent to nwritten = fwrite(buffer, 1, nread, outFile);
    int nwritten = 0;
    while (nwritten < nread) {
        ssize_t nw = write(outFile, buffer + nwritten, nread - nwritten);
        if (nw < 0) {
            if (errno == EINTR)
                continue;
            perror("writing report");
            status = 1;
            break;
        }
        if (nw == 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "cannot write data\n");
            status = 1;
            break;
        }
        nwritten += nw;
    }
    close(inFile);
    close(outFile);

    printf("%d bytes read, %d bytes written\n", nread, nwritten);
    return status;
}
```

Comment: cant use fopen for my class.  I really dont undestand why.

Comment: If your class is about unix system calls or system programming in general, that's understandable. look up `man open` and use the 3 argument version if you want create the output file.

Comment: Wow invocations of read() and write() are wrong even after your warning. Where loop?

Comment: @Joshua: Answer painfully updated, possibly still incorrect :)

Comment: I don't spot any errors. In any case; it's difficult to separate details from operation being performed without re-implementing stdio itself. I know the pain; implementing a read line function is several hundred lines.

Comment: @EthanBullock: read the comments and study the code: handling the partial reads and writes and temporary failures might be the purpose of this requirement for your class :)

Answer (score 1):

Tag: `linux`

```
FILE *inFile = fopen("dataFlow.dat", "r"); // read only
FILE *outFile = fopen("report.dat", "w"); // write only
```

```
int inFile = open("dataFlow.dat", O_RDONLY); // read only
int outFile = open("report.dat", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 0666); // write only
```

Open is a weird function; if the call cannot create a file it takes two arguments, but if it can create a file it takes three arguments. The third argument is `0666` until proven otherwise; `umask` will be applied.

The return can't be passed to stdio functions except `fdopen` but can be used directly using `read()`, `write()`, `lseek()`, and `close()`.

The return of open is a integer file handle or -1 for error.

(Posted answer while chqrle's answer was very wrong. He's proceeding to fix.)